# Koala Gem Album photos in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, photos, koala

I'm trying to display facebook album photos on my rails 3.12 app via the Koala gem by first accessing the users albums.  I know how get the album:

```
u.facebook.get_connections('me', 'albums')
```

but there is no direct access to the individual albums photos.  There is a link in the album object to a facebook page that shows all the album photos but that is about it.  I need to be able to drill down further via the graph API to get the individual photo objects but I don't know how to do so with Koala.  I prefer Koala based solutions but I am open to any solutions at all.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

I was able to drill down and access the photos inside the album by using the following:

```
current_user.facebook.get_connections("me","albums", :fields => "name, photos.fields(source)")
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to use the "user_photos" access_token.
and then fetch the id of the album usign :

```
albums = u.facebook.get_connections('me', 'albums')
```

then extract the album you want, 
and use the id of the album to fetch photos :

```
get_connections('#{album['id']}', 'photos')
```

I haven't tried it in ruby (I used the graph explorer), so tell me if it works :)

Comment: Your interpolated string needs to be surrounded by double quotes: `"#{album['id']}"`

Answer (score 2):

This just worked for me!
@graph.get_connections(album['**ALBUM_ID**'], "photos"])